# Access Android reference style color attribute programmatically

Tags: android

While in XML resources I can use a system reference style color like this (*just an example*):

```
android:textColor="?android:itemTextColor">
```

I would like to know how to get that color in java programmatically, when I need to set that color like this (*unrelated another example*):

```
button.setBackgroundColor(myColor);
```

How can I set `myColor` to be `?android:itemTextColor` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does something like this help?

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.textColorHint, typedValue, true);
button.setBackgroundColor(typedValue.data);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing there is an attribute, it's a reference for a resource (not necessarily a color). An attributes is resolved by a `Theme`, this means that the same attributes can be resolved to different values according to the `Theme` by which are resolved.

If you are in an `Acitivity` you can (and probably should) use the `Activity`'s theme

```
val typedValue = TypedValue()
val found = theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.textColorHint,typedValue, true)
```

After that you should check the type of the value you've resolved

```
when(typedValue.type){
    TypedValue.TYPE_INT_COLOR_ARGB8 -> ...
    TypedValue.TYPE_INT_COLOR_ARGB4 -> ...
    ...
}
```

And then you could (eventually) use the value of the color which is stored in `typedValue.data`